# Extract org heading title without task count e. g. [0/0]

Tags: org-mode, functions

I would like to extract just the plain name of an org heading:

I tried with `(nth 4 (org-heading-components))`

Example:

```
* Some Heading Title [0/1]              ;; cursor in this line when executing
** TODO Some Todo Item

-> result is "Some Heading Title [0/1]"

-> desired result would be "Some Heading Title"
```

Comment: I would send a bug report to the Org mode mailing list. I don't see any reason why the statistics cookie should be part of the title: it should be a separate component.

Comment: Its on my TODO-list now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(replace-regexp-in-string
  " \\[[[:digit:]]*[/%][[:digit:]]*\\]" "" 
  (nth 4 (org-heading-components)))
```

Comment: There are two forms of statistics cookie, one like this `[/]` and one like this: `[%]`, so you might want to generalize the regexp to catch them both. BTW, initially they might be empty skeletons without numbers until they are first evaluated, so you might want to take that into account too.

Comment: Thanks @NickD, amended.